# Can't find new linux modules list

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have the following problem:

I've just rebuilt the Linux kernel (was 3.13.0-24, now 3.15.5) of my Ubuntu to add some modules which are responsible for providing some virtual features (vfio in particular). The problem is that when I'm trying to load VFIO module using "sudo modprobe vfio" command the system responds that it "could not open moddep file /lib/modules/3.15.5/modules.dep.bin".
This answer makes sense because there is no such the path in the system. In the /lib/modules directory there is only one directory: 3.13.0-24-generic. I tried to find modules.dep.bin file using "find". It found it in only one directory: 3.13.0-24-generic.

So I have no clue how to get over this problem. Could someone please give me a hint what went wrong?

Comment: after making `sudo make modules_install` have you rebooted ..?

Comment: I rebooted it after I performed all installation commands:sudo make modules install, sudo make install, sudo update-grub. I didn't reboot it between these commands

Comment: once you `sudo make install' and update-grub reboot and check it.

Comment: `make modules_install` should have created `/lib/modules/3.15.5`. How exactly did you rebuild the kernel?